# How does the start of client to server communication work (java)

Tags: java, sockets

Note: I know there are answers to this question but could you please keep it simple because I don't need to understand the details, I just need to paint the picture in my head of how the following works and to be honest I am not that smart so I get lost in to much detail.

Lets consider following code:

```
//server
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
   Server() throws IOException {
   ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket( 4711 );
   while ( true ) {
   Socket client = server.accept();
   InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
   OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
   int multiplikator1 = in.read();
   int multiplikator2 = in.read();
   int resultat = multiplikator1 * multiplikator2;
   out.write(resultat);
   }
 }

//main server

public static void main (String[] args) {
 try {
   Server server = new Server();
 } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 } 
}

//client

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Client {
 Client() throws IOException {
 Socket server = new Socket ( "localhost", 4711 );
 InputStream in = server.getInputStream();
 OutputStream out = server.getOutputStream();
 out.write( 4 );
 out.write( 9 );
 int result = in.read();
 System.out.println( result );
 server.close();
 }

//client main 

public static void main (String[] args) {
 try {
 Client client = new Client();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 } 
}
```

So what I don't understand are the lines `Socket client = server.accept();` and `Socket server = new Socket ( "localhost", 4711 );`

```
Server 1* <----------------------> 2* Client

note 1* 2* represents socket
```

Does the line `Socket client = server.accept();` create a socket on the server side i.e Socket (1*) or is it the other way around?

And does the line `Socket server = new Socket ( "localhost", 4711 );` create socket (2*) which then sends some kind of initial message to the ServerSocket (`ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket( 4711 );` ) and then upon receiving that initial message `accept method` starts working and creates a socket (1*) is this how it works?

Comment: read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) - A new Socket s is created

Comment: The [`ServerSocket.accept()` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--) is the **first** place to look. The `Socket` returned by `server.accept()` is the connection from the client on the server. `ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket( 4711 );` listens on port 4711 for incoming client connections. It just listens, once a client connects the communication happens over the other `Socket`.

Comment: i did and in my opinion its this way as i described it but as i understood it from the video lecture its the other way around

Comment: @user12394078 What video lecture? If you are in a class, ask your instructor.

Comment: ok, the problem is i will be able to ask him next week, thanks anyway sorry if the question is too stupid

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes the server listens on the port 4711 and the action() method waits until there is a request but to send the request client has to create the socket first which means that the socket 2* is created first? is that correct ? and then after the socket 1* is created they can start the communication ?

Comment: with A and B trying to talk to each other, at least one of them has to be listening for a new connection – that's what `accept()` does. if neither A nor B is listening, they will never connect. say that A is listening and B is not – that means A cannot do anything to talk with B directly, because B isn't listening. A can only sit there, waiting indefinitely. if / when B tries to connect with A, that's when a connection happens. typically we would say "A" is the server, and "B" is the client.